# Aspx.cs doesn't recognize controls declared in aspx?

Tags: asp.net

I created a branch new web project:
File -> New -> Project  -> ASP.NET Web Application

Then I tried to add a simple control asp:Label but the aspx.cs doesn't recognize this declaration for some reasons. I didn't make any changes to the default project. It contains 6 pages:

[image]

Does anyone know what could cause this issue? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here what I added to the file `About.aspx` is a label with id = `id1`

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:label ID="id1" runat="server" >A Label</asp:label>
    <h2>
        About
    </h2>
    <p>
        Put content here.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

I ran the project without calling that variable `id1`, everything works fine.

[image]

But if I called `id1` within `About.aspx.cs`, it gave me error said the variable was not found.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2 {
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            id1.Text = "What the heck?";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the aspx page and aspx.cs and also the aspx.designer.cs code?

Comment: ok now coming to the specific point can you tell us which page u have placed the `asp:label` and where are u getting the error.... we cant explain you until we know the base cause of the problem.

Comment: Could you share some code and be more specific with the issue. I suspect that the CodeFile, Inherits attributes in your aspx page directive is pointing to the wrong values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on you comment it seems your your `About.aspx.designer.cs` file is missing the Label definition. Delete your `About.aspx.designer.cs` file and to regenerate it, right click on the Project (`WebApplication2`) and Choose '`Convert To Web Application`' this will regenerate your `About.aspx.designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean your solution and rebuild it,most preferably this problem is because of wrong Inherits attribute in .aspx file